# Merging multiple csv files

Tags: c++

I have many 1GB csv files. What is the easiest way to merge them. Can this be done using shell commands or do I have to write a C++ program for it.

Comment: Depends. Do they all have the same table headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat *.csv > mega-merged.csv2
mv mega-merged.csv2 mega-merged.csv
```

(The use of the `.csv2` is so that the `*.csv` doesn't catch it.)

Re Joce's comment, if you have headers, you can trim off all the headers (on GNU/Linux or any other platform with GNU tools) using something like:

```
tail -qn +2 *.csv > mega-merged.csv2
```